# Bus error: 10 when running c++ output file (no compilation error)

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, printf, runtime-error

I'm trying out some coding questions for the sake of practising c++, but I'm running into bus error. (My code compiled fine!)

Here is the code that I wrote.

In my main function, I call test7().
test7() essentially creates a 4x3 test matrix that is used to test for the function, zerotheMatrix(). 
The function looks for an element that is '0' and sets its entire row and column to 0.

```
void zeroTheMatrix(int** matrix, int m, int n)
{
    bool zeroRows[m];
    bool zeroCols[n];

    for(unsigned int g = 0; g < m; g++)
    {
        zeroRows[g] = false;
    }
    for(unsigned int g1 = 0; g1 < n; g1++)
    {
        zeroCols[g1] = false;
    }

    printf("Original matrix:\n");
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%i ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(unsigned int r = 0; r < m; r++)
    {
        for(unsigned int c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            if(matrix[r][c] == 0)
            {
                zeroRows[r] = 1;
                zeroCols[c] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for(unsigned int r2 = 0; r2 < m; r2++)
    {
        for(unsigned int c2 = 0; c2 < n; c2++)
        {
            if(zeroRows[r2] == 1 || zeroCols[c2] == 1)
                matrix[r2][c2] = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("Zeroed matrix:\n");
    for(unsigned int final = 0; final < m; final++)
    {
        for(unsigned int final2 = 0; final2 < n; final2++)
        {
            printf("%i ", matrix[final][final2]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void test7()
{
    int row = 4;
    int col = 3;
    int **matrix;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < row; i++)   // n^2
    {
        unsigned int num = i*col;
        matrix[i] = new int[col];
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if( i != 0 && (j/i) > 1)
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            else
                matrix[i][j] = num;
            num++;      
            //printf("matrix[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }   
    zeroTheMatrix(matrix, row, col);
}
```

Here is the output from the terminal:

```
Original matrix:
0 1 2 
3 4 0 
6 7 8 
9 10 11 
Zeroed matrix:
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 7 0 
0 10 0 
Bus error: 10
```

Thank you

Comment: `matrix[i] = ...` um, where's the `matrix = new int*[row];` to setup the initial pointer array ? (spoiler: there is none). Your code invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: What he said ^, plus, bus error typically means "You can't write there."

Comment: And watch out for these bad boys: `bool zeroRows[m];
    bool zeroCols[n];` Variable Length arrays are non standard, so they don't port well, and are a really easy way to blow up your stack.